# Не получается засунуть свой код в exe файл через pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, pyinstaller

У меня  есть код, который нормально работает в pycharm, но я его хочу запихнуть в exe. Я использую pyinstaller и когда я пытаюсь сделать pyinstaller filename.py у меня выдаёт Error, покажу на скрине ниже. Код тоже прикреплю ниже
Ещё я попробовал запустить код не с pyCharm, а создать файл .py и после после запуска файла он сразу закрывается.В коде присутствует работа с xml и сам эрор связан с 'utf-8'

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom import minidom

name = input('Введите полный нейм БС:')
MRBTS = input('Введите MRBTS БС:')
Cells1800 = input('Введите перечень Сот 1800 (через запятую):')
Cells2600 = input('Введите перечень Сот 2600 (через запятую):')

Cells1800 = tuple(int(x) for x in Cells1800.split(","))
Cells2600 = tuple(int(x) for x in Cells2600.split(","))

CAREL = {'class': "CAREL"}

strDistName1 = 'PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-' + str(MRBTS) + '/LNBTS-' + str(MRBTS) + '/LNCEL-' + str(Cells1800) +  '/CAREL-1'
strDistName2 = 'PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-' + str(MRBTS) + '/LNBTS-' + str(MRBTS) + '/LNCEL-' + str(Cells2600) +  '/CAREL-1'



#import pylab as p

def main():
    new = ET.Element('raml', version = '2.0', xmlns='raml20.xsd')
    cmData = ET.SubElement(new, 'cmData', xmlns="", type='plan', scope='changes', name='KIE_KIE_NV9_DUL_1')
    header = ET.SubElement(new, 'header')
    log = ET.SubElement(header, 'log', dateTime='29.09.2021', action="created", appInfo="PlanExporter")
    log.text = 'InternalValues are used'
    x = 0
    x1 = 0
    NCarel = 1
    while x < len(Cells1800):
        while x1 <len(Cells2600):
            managedObject = ET.SubElement(cmData, 'managedObject', CAREL,version="xL20B_2003_002", distName='PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-' + str(MRBTS) + '/LNBTS-' + str(MRBTS) + '/LNCEL-' + str(Cells1800[x]) +  '/CAREL-' + str(NCarel) , operation="create")
            defaults = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'defaults',name="System")
            p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name="lcrId")
            p1.text = str(Cells2600[x1])
            p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name="lnBtsId")
            p1.text = str(MRBTS)
            p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name="maxNumOfSuppMimoLayer")
            p1.text = '2'
            p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name="pcellSwapAllowed")
            p1.text = '1'
            x1 += 1
            NCarel += 1
        NCarel = 1
        x1 = 0
        x += 1

    x = 0
    x1 = 0
    while x < len(Cells2600):
        while x1 <len(Cells1800):
            managedObject = ET.SubElement(cmData, 'managedObject',version="xL20B_2003_002", distName='PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-' + str(MRBTS) + '/LNBTS-' + str(MRBTS) + '/LNCEL-' + str(Cells2600[x]) +  '/CAREL-' + str(NCarel) , ooperation="create")
            defaults = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'defaults',name="System")
            p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name="lcrId")
            p1.text = str(Cells1800[x1])
            p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name="lnBtsId")
            p1.text = str(MRBTS)
            p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name="maxNumOfSuppMimoLayer")
            p1.text = '2'
            p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name="pcellSwapAllowed")
            p1.text = '1'
            x1 += 1
            NCarel += 1
        NCarel = 1
        x1 = 0
        x += 1

    managedObject = ET.SubElement(cmData, 'managedObject', version="xL20B_2003_002",distName='PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-' + str(MRBTS) + '/LNBTS-' + str(MRBTS) + '/CADPR-0', id="41429697", operation="create")
    defaults = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'defaults', name="System")
    p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name='a3Offset')
    p1.text = '-6'
    p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name='a3TimeToTrigger')
    p1.text = '320'
    p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name='a3TriggerQuantity')
    p1.text = '0'
    p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name='a6Offset')
    p1.text = '6'
    p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name='a6ReportInterval')
    p1.text = '640'
    p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name='a6TimeToTrigger')
    p1.text = '8'
    p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name='enableA3Event')
    p1.text = '1'
    p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name='enableA6Event')
    p1.text = '1'
    p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name='enableFreqPrioSwap')
    p1.text = '0'
    p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name='hysA3Offset')
    p1.text = '2'
    p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name='hysA6Offset')
    p1.text = '0'
    p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name='maxNumMimoLayerFdd')
    p1.text = '10'
    p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name='maxNumScellSwaps')
    p1.text = '0'
    p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name='sFreqPrio')
    p1.text = '1'
    p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name='scellMeasThreshRsrp')
    p1.text = '-110'
    p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name='scellMeasThreshRsrq')
    p1.text = '-120'
    p1 = ET.SubElement(managedObject, 'p', name='scellPdcchOlLa')
    p1.text = '2'



    save_xml('test.xml', new)


def save_xml(NSNTEST, xml_code):
    xml_string = ET.tostring(xml_code).decode()

    xml_prettyxml = minidom.parseString(xml_string).toprettyxml()
    with open('C:\Pyton\File for open\MyXml.xml', 'w') as xml_file:
        xml_file.write(xml_prettyxml)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже подобный вопрос [задавали на анлоязычной версии форума](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47692960/error-when-using-pyinstaller-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byt)

Рещением там было добавить флаг игнорирования ошибки декодирования в файл `Python\Lib\site-packages\Pyinstaller\compat.py`

`.decode()` => `.decode(errors='ignore')` или `.decode(errors="replace")`

Но обязательно проверьте на вашем варианте данных - игнорирование ошибок может дать некорректный результат

Answer (score 0):

возможно имеет смысл добавить в самом начале это:

```
# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-
```

где указана кодировка файла.